# Difference in numpy array masking

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

I have three numpy arrays, one the source array, one destination array and one mask array. I want to replace the values in the destination with the same values from the source only at the places where the mask is equal to one.

My naiive try was:

```
import numpy as np
destination = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
source = np.ones((3,3))
mask = np.zeros((3,3)).astype(np.uint8)
mask[1,1]=1

destination[mask] = source[mask]
```

which leads me to `destination` being

```
[[1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [6, 7, 8]]
```

whereas I expect it to be

```
[[0, 1, 2],
 [3, 1, 5],
 [6, 7, 8]].
```

I do get the correct result, when I do

```
destination[mask==1] = source[mask==1].
```

My question is: Why are these two commands not identical, or what does the first even do?

Comment: Why are using `np.uint8` for a mask? Shouldn't that be a boolean array?

Comment: Check what `source[mask]` is giving you

Comment: Fair, if I cast it to boolean, it does what it should. But my question remains, what does my first version actually do?

Comment: @Divakar I came from this side, and understanding what's going on is exactly the problem I have, hence asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must check inside the matrices and which matrix gives you what you want.

```
mask
```

**Output**

```
[[0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0]]
```

but `destination[mask == 1]` gives you a boolean matrix

```
mask == 1
```

**Output**

```
[[False, False, False],
 [False,  True, False],
 [False, False, False]]
```

whereas:

```
destination[mask]
```

**Output**

```
[[[0, 1, 2],
  [0, 1, 2],
  [0, 1, 2]]

[[0, 1, 2],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [0, 1, 2]],

[[0, 1, 2],
 [0, 1, 2],
 [0, 1, 2]]]
```

but using `destination[mask == 1]` gives you a single value which is 4. It's the same for the `source[mask == 1]` which gives you the single value 1.

and if you use `destination[mask==1] = source[mask==1]` instead of `destination[mask] = source[mask]`  you will only change the value 4 in the destination matrix.

I hope my explanation is clear.

**Edit:**

I hope I understand your question correct:

The simple integer indexing structure `x[[i]]` gives you the i'th row of the matrix.

So `destination[0,1,2]` gives:

```
[[0, 1, 2],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [6, 7, 8]]
```

and for an understandable example the input `destination[1,2,0]` leads to

```
[[3, 4, 5],
 [6, 7, 8],
 [0, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: Yes this helps. I still have to figure what the integer indexing together with broadcasting really is doing, but this put me in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you so much. I edited your answer for better readability but now it makes sense to me. So, I was taking lines from my original matrix and because my index-space is a 3-tuple broadcasting to a 3-D matrix happens.